# Using CharCodeAt with index not sentence

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This question is previously asked by different ways but not same as this one.  I want to achieve by Using ES5 or ES6 to write a function that calculates the word with the highest score using the `system A = 1, B = 2, C = 3 etc.` The string will only contain a single space between words and there will be no punctuation.

I have came up with this function.

```
var wordScoreCalculator = s =>
  s.toLowerCase().
  split('').
  map(s => s.charCodeAt(0)-0x60).
  filter(c => 1 <= c && c <= 26).
  reduce((x,y) => x+y, 0);

wordScoreCalculator('I live in this world');
```

Currently, charCodeAt is mapping with whole sentence and it calculating all words together to 208.

I want to make it to work with index so it calculate each word individually and display the highest score only.

In this case, it should display 72. How this can be achieved?

Many thanks !

Comment: Perhaps change the letter s to w, in the parameter given to the anonymous function in map?

Answer (score 1):

You need to additionally map each *word*, splitting on a space first. Also, because, per the condition `The string will only contain a single space between words and there will be no punctuation`, there's no need for the `filter`, since it sounds like the words will always contain alphabetical characters:

```js
var wordScoreCalculator = s =>
  s.toLowerCase()
  .split(' ')
  .map(word => word
    .split('')
    .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)-0x60)
    .reduce((x,y) => x+y, 0)
  )
  .reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))

console.log(wordScoreCalculator('I live in this world'));
console.log(wordScoreCalculator('I live in this world zzzz'));
```

Or maybe abstract the operation that maps words to their value into its own function, for better readability:

```js
const wordToScore = word => word
  .split('')
  .map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)-0x60)
  .reduce((x,y) => x+y, 0);
const bestWordCalculator = s =>
  s.toLowerCase()
  .split(' ')
  .map(wordToScore)
  .reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b));
  
console.log(bestWordCalculator('I live in this world'));
console.log(bestWordCalculator('I live in this world zzzz'));
```

Comment: Somewhat of a formatting improvement or refactor (depends on how you want to look at it) would be to preserve OP's initial function and then make a new one for sentences: `sentenceScoreCalculator => s => s.split(' ').map(wordScoreCalculator)`

Comment: Is this ES5 or ES6 ?

Comment: @Webappsdeva it's ES6 but only due to the arrow functions.

Comment: @Webappsdeva Your original code is in ES6 as well. (To turn into ES5, use Babel and polyfills, as always)